# Using Purrr package to produce plots with correct xlab

Tags: r, plot, purrr

I am trying to use the `map` function from `Purrr` package to produce a bunch of plots at one time. I met issues with the `xlab` title.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- mtcars

df %>% keep(is.numeric) %>%
       map(~qplot(.), geom = 'density')
```

The `xlab` of each resulting plot turns to be `.`. I have tried to include `xlab = .` into the function, but it does not work. How can I add the correct `xlab` (e.g., the column name) to each plot? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `imap` instead of `map` and use the `.y` in `xlab`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
   keep(is.numeric) %>%
   imap(~qplot(.x) + 
           geom_density() + 
           xlab(.y))
```

-output (last plot)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! @akrun. My first time to know there is another function `imap` in the package. Could you explain a bit how/why the `.y` works here? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`map` only iterates the columns, not the names of the columns. You can also iterate the names with `imap`. For example

```
df %>% keep(is.numeric) %>%
  imap(~qplot(.x, xlab=.y, geom = 'density'))
```